# Is H2O DAI's MLI display menu dependent on the algorithms used in its experiments?

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

I see H2O DAI picks up the optimized algorithm for the dataset automatically.  I hear that the contents of MLI (machine learning interpretation) from other platforms (like SAS Viya) is dependent on the algorithm it uses. For example, LOCO is not available for GBM, etc. (Of course, this is a purely hypothetical example.)

Is it the same with H2O DriverlessAI ?  Or does it always show the same MLI menus regardless of the algorithms it used?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, MLI will always display the same dashboard for any DAI algorithm, with the following exceptions: Shapley plots are not currently supported for RuleFit and TensorFlow models, Multinomial currently only show Shapley and Feature Importance (global and local), and Time Series experiments are not yet supported for MLI. What this means is you can expect to always see: K-LIME/LIME-SUP, Surrogate Decision Tree, Partial Dependence Plot and Individual Conditional Expectation. Note this may change in the future, for the most up-to-date details please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/interpreting.html#understanding-the-model-interpretation-page).